# MySQL - Can I RIGHT JOIN a list of values?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to find the right join result of a table in db and a list of values I have obtained somewhere else. This is what I have so far

```
SELECT * 
FROM new_assets n 
RIGHT JOIN ( VALUES ('0253608','test_name1')
                  , ('2311194', 'test_name2') AS v(id, name)) ON v.name=n.name;
```

I keep getting errors saying syntax error around `(VALUES ('0253608','test_name1'), ('2311194', 'test_name2')`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but not in MySQL.  MySQL does not support `VALUES()` in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 8):

MySQL does not support `VALUES()` in the `FROM` clause.  Just use `SELECT` and `UNION ALL`.  Also, I would write this as a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT '0253608' as id, 'test_name1' as name UNION ALL
      SELECT '2311194', 'test_name2'
     ) v LEFT JOIN
     new_assets n;
```

For most people, it is easier to follow the `LEFT JOIN`.  It says to keep all the rows in the *first* table and then matching rows in subsequent tables; this works when you chain them together.  This is typically easier to follow then following a chain and saying that the last table has all the rows.

Comment: if the list of values is very long, do you recommend using LEFT JOIN or creating a TEMPORARY TABLE?

Comment: I'm not sure about Gordon, but I would suggest if the list is very long you should possibly create a permanent table, or add the values as a new column to an existing one.

Comment: MySQL does support VALUES as of version 8.0.19: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/values.html

Comment: `UNION ALL` to build the list.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just write it like this?

```
SELECT n.*
  , CASE `name` 
    WHEN 'test_name1' THEN '0253608' 
    WHEN 'test_name2' THEN '2311194' 
  END AS id
FROM new_assets AS n
WHERE n.`name` IN ('test_name1', 'test_name2')
;
```

You can get rid of the repeated string literals if you replace the `WHERE ...` with `HAVING id IS NOT NULL`; though it may not perform as well.